# Forward traffic from one network to another in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

let's say that we have two VPC networks in GCP - `A` and `B` within same project. There is an internal load balancer run in `B (192.168.0.1)`. Is it possible to pass-through whole IP traffic from some IP address in network `A` (let's say `10.0.0.1`) to load balancer in `B`?

Comment: You can connect them using a VPC peering

Comment: Yes, I know. But I would like to have a situation like:
when any VM within `A` make a request to 10.0.0.1 it is forwarded to loadbalancer in `B` network. How to do it?

Comment: You can check [Internal Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering#spec-ilb) with regards the internal passthrough network load balancer. Then this one for  [internal Application Load Balancers](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal/internal-https-lb-and-other-networks#using-vpc-network-peering)

Comment: I also want to reiterate that it is also possible using vpc peering based from this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/internal/internal-tcp-udp-lb-and-other-networks#using-vpc-network-peering) wherein it was mentioned that the subnet routes allow traffic from peer network to reach internal load balancer in your network while following the requirements shown in the documentation.

Comment: For internal passthrough Network Load Balancer configuration, this is possible considering you need to exchange a custom static route and use internal passthrough Network Load Balancer as next hop. Check [Route exchange options](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering#route-exchange-options)

Comment: @YvanG., is it possible to forward traffic from one loadbalancer to the another?